# What is Invalid leaf [ error in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

When applying filter to a many2many field I'm getting this error.

Field Definition in python is: 
Here is field definition in python

```
fields.Many2many(string='AnalysisProfile',
                    comodel_name='olims.analysis_profile',
                    relation='ar_to_analysisprofile',
                    domain="[('Deactivated', '=',False )]"
```

and in XML View:

```
 <field name="AnalysisProfile" string="Analysis Profile"></field>
```

I'm getting following error:

raise ValueError("Invalid leaf %s" % str(self.leaf))

ValueError: Invalid leaf [

Comment: Would you please share your code. So we can understand a problem.

Comment: I'm new to odoo. I dont know where  filter functionality is defined.

Comment: @MuhammadSajid Are you making some kind of modifications? If so, please include them. This is most likely an issue with a field definition or trying to use a `domain` improperly.

Comment: Yes @travisw, I'm making modifications. No I'm just filtering record from GUI and getting error

Comment: I think you either missed closing/opening parenthesis or try to use a nonexisting field in condition. Here is the example `domain = "[('groups_id','=',group_id)]"`

Comment: what do you mean by "try to use a non existing field in condition." The field exists  and its type is many2many. @KbiR

Comment: @MuhammadSajid Update your question to add the field definition in Python and in XML

Comment: @Mohammed Sajid, at least update your question with the code which you tried.

Comment: I've updated field definition in question @KbiR . Please see

Comment: @MuhammadSajid could you please share more code and/or the full error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added extra double quotes in the domain, remove it and try.

```py
fields.Many2many(string='AnalysisProfile',
                comodel_name='olims.analysis_profile',
                relation='ar_to_analysisprofile',
                domain=[('Deactivated', '=',False )])
```

And make sure you defined a field `Deactivated` (Uppercase letter D) in `olims.analysis_profile`.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @KbiR Solved

Comment: But now on sorting to that column I'm getting this error

       File "/home/developer/odoo-9.0rc20171218/openerp/sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/odoo-9.0rc20171218/openerp/sql_db.py", line 233, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ..., 60, 61, 63, 68, 187, 188, 362, 364, 375, 376)))),  to_numb...

Comment: You may need to add `store=True` To your Python field definition in order for it to be sortable.

Comment: the extra double quotes aren't the mistake, please remove that wrong assumption from this as correct marked answer. You will find a lot of quoted field domain definitions in Odoo code. Maybe the second part is the big problem here, but nobody knows until the questioner shares more code...

Answer (score 2):

In Odoo, a domain comparison consists in a 3-leaf tuple such as:

```
('field', "=", 'value')
```

That error message typically means that one of those 3 leaves is wrong. Check your domain to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Python file:

```py
def _analysis_profile(self):

    return [('Deactivated', '=', False)]

AnalysisProfile = fields.Many2many(string='AnalysisProfile',
                    comodel_name='olims.analysis_profile',
                   relation='ar_to_analysisprofile',
                   domain=_analysis_profile)
```

XML file:

```xml
<field name="AnalysisProfile" string="Analysis Profile" widget="many2many_tags"></field>
```

---